# In arcgis how do I filter my geo data in a certain state?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I currently have a database of points that contains latitude and longitude. What I want to do is to filter out all the points so that only the ones that are in Texas will show. I have done a spatial join with the target as the points and the join as the state, but it still shows all the points from the original set.

Comment: What software are you using?  A [Clip](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000800000004000000) in just about any software package will give you a new dataset of only points within the clipping polygon.

Comment: I am using arcgis. That tool sounds exactly like what I am looking for. I'm going to take a look into it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you have done a spatial join with the state layer, and there is a state name in the point layer now, you can use a definition query to only include points with that state name value included.  access the definition query from the layer properties in the definition query tab and use the query builder to make your expression (i.e. [state] = 'Texas')